# searching on sorted linked list

Tags: java, linked-list

im working a search method on a linked list this my code

```
Node item=head;
 String help=item.getKonten();
 System.out.printf("data to search");
    search=input.nextLine();

    while (help.compareTo(search)>0){
        if (help.equals(search)){
            System.out.println ("index " + index);
            ktemu=1;
        } else {
            item=item.getLink();
            bantu1=item.getKonten();        
        }
        index++;
    }

    if (ktemu == 0){
         System.out.println("data not found");
    }
```

the output
data : 1,2,3,4,5
data to search 2
data not found
anyone can point me whre this code goes wrong so the index not shown up

Comment: Just a suggestion: when posting code, if it's not a lot of it, you might want to rename the variables to something easier to understand in English. It helps people understand your code faster and help you out better

Comment: ty editted just forget bout it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`compareTo` method returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object is less than, equal to, or greater than the specified object.

So when you compare 1 with 2 which return negative value and `-1>0` becomes false. So it come out of loop.

Comment: ok if i change it to while (help.compareTo(search)!=1) i got nullpointerexepcion and why.. what i mean is while help still lower than search keep looping..

Comment: as u put condition `!= 1` so even -1 then also `-1!=1`  is true.

Comment: ok got it.. but even with <=0  i got nullpointerexecption.. any suggestion why?

Comment: you can debug this out but I would suggest you see this problem in some other way I mean do loop like that. you are actually searching a value in List. possible easiest and optimal way to do it `Collections#frequency` which returns the number of elements in the specified collection equal to the specified object.

Comment: hmm im just curious with this unique algorithm tht just i found.. logically true but don't know what is going wrong with that nullpointer..

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating for as long as `bantu1` is not the same as `cari`, but you do so using the compare interface. Why not use equals directly? Anyway, if you do want to use the compare method, as @Quoi says, you need to consider that it might be < 0, so, `!=0` might be more suitable.

How about this:

```
private boolean find(Object input);
    while (true){
        if(item.equals(input)){
            return true;
        } else {
            if(item.getLink() == null) {
                 return false;
            } else {
                item=item.getLink();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it is search for sorted linked list so what i mean is if the help already higher from   the search so the loop stopped

Comment: You mean it is a *sorted* linked list then. Then the above comment applies: if you find the *right* one, compare will give you back 0